# Is there any way to call google initMap callback function outside the google API URL?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am using google map API which contain initMap callback function, I need to call this function outside the google map API URL for example I am using:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I need to remove last part of query string `&callback=initMap` but when I remove google map does not work.

Problem is I want to use this same google map api for all google api related stuff hence some APIs does not have initMap method thats why I want to call this method separably is it possible.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to call the `initMap` function asynchronously.

Change (looks like it is missing the "async defer"):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Then call the initMap function after the map div has been rendered in the DOM.

**Note:** there is a reason that Google has changed all their examples to asynchronously load the API (page load speed), all their examples were originally done with an onload function.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Your same example is not working at my end I used exactly same code can you please create it on JSFiddle if you don't mind :)

Answer (score -3):

You can call `initMap` after delay, `setTimeout(initMap, 500);`

Comment: I don't think so, you are relying on the fact that the google maps api script loads in 500ms which could or COULD not happen (according to the users' connection speed).